# table showing null value instead of zero

Tags: php

i want to make this table

```html
!  ID   !   A  !    B   !   C   !   D   !   average   !
-------------------------------------------------------
! 01    !      !    0   !   10  !       !      5      !
! 02    !      !        !       !       !             !
! 03    !   0  !    0   !       !   0   !      0      !
```

i use this function

```html
 
  if ($A == "" ) {$countA="0";} else { $countA = "1"; }
  if ($B == "" ) {$countB="0";} else { $countB = "1"; }
  if ($C == "" ) {$countC="0";} else { $countC = "1"; }
  if ($D == "" ) {$countD="0";} else { $countD = "1"; }
            
$sum  = ($A + $B + $C + $D);
$ceksum =($countA + $countB + $countC + $countD);

  if ($ceksum == "0") {
             $average="";
   } else { $average = $sum/$ceksum; }

and php that i use to call the data is

echo ($averageled4amatt4h=="")?'':round($averageled4amatt4h,1);
```

but the table shows this result..(with null data in average when zero is the only value)

```html
!  ID   !   A  !    B   !   C   !   D   !   average   !
-------------------------------------------------------
! 01    !      !    0   !   10  !       !      5      !
! 02    !      !        !       !       !             !
! 03    !   0  !    0   !       !   0   !             !
```

what should i do? i'm still learning coding...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ($ceksum == "0") {
         $average="0"; // <- change this line
        } else { $average = $sum/$ceksum; }
```

Comment: it came up with average zero for all null data  (the average of data 02 is zero but data 03 is null) i want the opposite

Answer (score 0):

modify this type of line:
`if ($A == "" ) {$countA="0";} else { $countA = "1"; }`

to

```
 $countA = !empty($A) ? "1" : 0;
 $countB = !empty($B) ? "1" : 0;
 $countC = !empty($C) ? "1" : 0;
```

Comment: still no change :(

Comment: you need to change`$sum` also $sum = ((empty($A) ? "1" : 0) + (empty($B) ? "1" : 0) + empty($C) ? "1" : 0 + empty($D) ? "1" : 0);

Comment: do you mean the $ceksum?